# SOQL date comparison for formula(date) date type

Tags: date, select, comparison, salesforce, soql

can anybody help me with writing a SOQL query. Using "Date" data type in WHERE statement is easy, it behaves like a normal Date would. But if the data type is "Formula(Date)" it seems like normal date time functions are not working. In sample query like

```
SELECT Date_of_purchase__c FROM Goods WHERE Date_of_purchase__c = 2011-11-04
```

all works fine if "Date_of_purchase__c" field is "Date" type. But the same query fails if the field type is "Formula(Date)". What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you 100% sure your formula is using the `date` type and not `datetime`? I just created a formula field on Contact to test, using the formula:

```
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)
```

I then ran the following code in the system log:

```
System.Debug([Select Name From Contact Where CreatedDateF__c = 2011-12-16]);
```

and I can see that it returned 20 rows.

Comment: Thanks for help! All I can see in Custom field definition details, is that data type is "Formula". The date is calculated from several other Formula fields. When you get the sample object, this field is in usual Y-m-d format. Now I believe Formula data types is not working both ways - they only work when getting the data, but you can't use them in where statement.

Comment: The sample I just showed is using the formula in a WHERE statement! :)  Perhaps wrap the whole thing in a DATEVALUE() just in case (in the formula). There's plenty of quirks on this platform!

Comment: Oh, I thought it was clear that I have no clues what am I doing here :) I will speak with org owners, if there is something they can do with DATEVALUE(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries - let me know how you go - curious as to what's going on there! Might be worth trying a datetime syntax, just in case: 2011-12-16T00:00Z for instance.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me at the right direction. Something was wrong in the way formula was written, nothing was wrong with the query. Thanks again. (all works now)

Comment: Interesting! Wonder if it just contained invalid values or something. Did they tell you what they had to change?